# План разработки веб-приложения на java

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Нужно написать небольшой проект, а-ля интернет магазина с простейшей авторизацией и БД (без spring boot). Знаю, что такое сервлеты, немножкo Spring и остальное по мелочи.

Проблема в плане. Точнее в его отсутствии. Я не знаю с чего начать, что и как делать дальше, чтобы хотя бы примерно где-то об этом почитать и т.п..

Может кто подсказать, с чего стоит начать, какому шаблону/плану придерживаться и т.д.?

Comment: Это учебная или тестовая задача?

Comment: Начните со схемы базы данных :)

Comment: Скорее учебная. Нужно написать проект в универ.

БД? А дальше? Я примерно продумал бизнес-логику и какие-то технические аспекты, но общего плана нет. Пытался найти какой-нибудь "живой" пример в интернете - тщетно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

1. Создаём схему БД. В ней описываем сущности типа клиент, админ, товар, категория товара.
2. Создаём API для доступа к БД. Если голые сервлеты брать, то, видимо, по сервлету на каждую сущность. Чтобы в итоге CRUD получился.
3. Авторизация/регистрация. Изучаете как делается нужная вам. Например `Basic Auth` по логину-паролю, которая возвращает, например, токен и/или сетит оный в куки через соответствующий заголовок ответа. Делаете её также в сервлете отдельном и как-то там применяете фильтры запросов к вашим сервлетам (ни разу не делал такого, но оно должно как-то работать)
4. Теперь фронт. Я бы его отдельно сделал, даже, наверное, на голых HTML+JS. Там просто пара HTML файлов с нужными кнопками типа `вход/регистрация`, ведущими на соответствующие HTML файлы. Плюс страницы со списком товаров и необходимые вещи типа покупки, добавления товара, корзины (зависит от ТЗ), где данные получаются/пишутся через JS, который дёргает API.

Comment: Оо, спасибо. Я вначале думал использовать голые сервлеты, но препод сказал, чтобы мы навесили всяких фреймворков, + будет, я решил использовать spring. С ним вроде же тоже самое?

Comment: @ImmRaytal, да, со спрингом примерно тоже самое. Там будет и сложнее и проще одновременно. Проще, т.к. много стандартного кода во фреймворке, сложнее, т.к. надо в нём разобраться, чтобы заставить его работать. И, раз уж вам фреймворков надо, то можно и для фронта взять что-то типа Angular.